# Angular5: conditional module for route

Tags: angular, angular-router

So, Angular app created with CLI

I have a modules Aversion2.module and Aversion1.module.
At HTML user can chose module version in dropdown element.
After that chosen module will be rendered in app.

Some ideas how to implement that:
1) in router use loadChildren property

```
...
loadChildren: getModule()
...
//pseudocode
getModule() {
 if (settings.version === 1) {
  return import './Aversion1.module#Amodule';
 } else {
  return import './Aversion2.module#Amodule';
 }
}
```

2) use CanLoad - redirect to another route with chosen version.

3) use Router.resetConfig

Maybe somebody have a working solution or experience how to implement that. Many thanks

Comment: loadChildren must be a string and must be relative agains src/ folder. https://v5.angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration

Comment: what about LoadChildrenCallback ?
https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildren

Comment: Use different paths for different children and overwrite the routerlinks according to the selected version.

Comment: @Alex Then you must use it via () => getModule()